# Datagrid Selected row in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am using DataGrid in my silverlight app. On the left side of the row when we click to select the entire row, at that particular time if someone press Delete key , i want to erase the values present in that row and not Delete the entire row from the grid itself.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

if your datagrid is bound with datasource then you can use something like below where Employee is the class the datagrid1 has collection of. This way you can, not only do it blank but you can assign default values if you want to and specifically.

```
        Employee emp = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Employee;
        emp.Name = "";
```